# Are there compelling reasons to use EventHandler<T> delegate instead of just Action<T> when declaring events?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

When I declare an event, I've been using the `Action` delegate or `Action<T, ...>` delegate if the event handler has parameters.  I recently noticed the existence of the `EventHandler` delegate, which requires a type param that inherits `EventArgs`.  The latter method requires that I create an additional class that exists only to encapsulate whatever parameters are passed with the event, which seems unnecessary, unless I'm missing something.

So, what *are* the reasons for using the `EventArgs` delegate when declaring an event?  What does it buy me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It buys you the ability to return event arguments, that's all.  If you have no need for that, then maybe you don't need an `EventHandler` delegate.

From a larger perspective, `EventArgs` is the "socially acceptable" way of getting data from one place to another using events.  You can create custom delegates to do this, of course, but `EventArgs` has tooling support in Visual Studio, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It provides you with an extensibility point for changing your event in the future.

Let's say I define a class `Car`:

```
public class Car { 
    String Make { get; set; }
    String Model { get; set; }
    int Year { get; set; }
}
```

and an event `CarBuilt`:

```
public event Action<Car> CarBuilt;
```

That's fine.  But then, what if I want the event to later include the person who built the car?  Using an action, I need to either change the event signature or add that information to the `Car` class (where it really doesnt belong).

If I define it this way instead:

```
public class CarBuiltEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public Car TheCar { get; set; }
}

public event EventHandler<CarBuiltEventArgs> CarBuilt;
```

Then I can add the BuiltBy property to the CarBuiltEventArgs class and I'm all set.

```
public class CarBuiltEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public Car TheCar { get; set; }
    public String BuiltBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You indicated you use Action if arguments are needed.  Comparing the two ask yourself what would be required if next year your requirements change and you need a new parameter passed in that event?  Do you change lots of code or just one class that inherits EventArgs?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason for using `EventHandler<T>` is probably that delegates of different types--even those types use the same method signature--are not interchangeable.  If one event uses an `EventHandler<fnordEventArgs>` and another uses an `Action<Object, fnordEventArgs>`, the same methods could be subscribed to both events, but delegates created for one event could not be used with the other.  Normally, this would be no big deal, since the statement like `FirstEvent += methodName` would translate into `FirstEvent += new EventHandler<fnordEventArgs>(methodName)`, and `SecondEvent += methodName` would translate into `FirstEvent += new Action<Object, fnordEventArgs>(methodName)`.  In some cases, however, it is necessary for an event subscriber to store the delegate used to subscribe.  For the subscriber to store the delegate, it must know its type--correctly.  Consistently using `EventHandler<T>` as the delegate for event handling methods of the form `void EventHandler(Object sender, T args)` makes it must easier to create the right delegate type.